# How can I get an alphabetized list of Albums in Apple Music on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-music

In Apple Music on iOS I'm trying to sort the albums in My Music alphabetically. It seems really intent on sorting by Artist and either making the Album name or the Artist's name more prominent on the list.

1. I chose sort by album, expecting it to be an alphabetized list of albums, but it's still alphabetized by artist and now the title of the album is prominent.
2. Now I'm sorting by artist, so artist is prominent, and the albums are less so.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings---> Music----> Library---->Sort Album----> By Title

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I was wondering why it was working that way. It just seems counterintuitive, but oh well. Now it's working the way my brain expects it to. Thank you. :)